# Advanced Web Page Transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I have been very into web development recently and I am comfortable with HTML, CSS, Javascript, jQuery, and Ajax. I have been very interested about making the transition from page to page smoother on the sites that I design. I have found what I think is a good example and I was wondering how you would approach building this sites page transitions (http://zadvorsky.com/). Thank you very much and if you have any other sources on page transitions I would love to look at them as well. I am not specifically interested in this one as much as overall page transitions but I think that this is a good basis as an example.

Answer (score 0):

The site you linked is using what's known as a **SPA ([Single Page Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application))**.

Frameworks that you can use to build SPAs quickly are

- [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/)
- [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)
- ...

For example, take a look at:

- [AngularJS's Animation docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations)
- [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) or more specifically the [Anchoring Demo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate#anchoring-demo)

Most between-page transitions are done by removing the concept of "pages" in the front-end app, and doing so in such a way that the user of the app does not notice that the concept has been removed.  As such, transitions become much easier when there's just one "page."

Comment: I considered that he was doing this, but you will notice that when you follow the links the page legitimately changes (in the address bar). This is the part that confused me the most. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: @tyC2014 just because the address bar changes, doesn't mean the page changed.  In your example's case, only the address bar changed, not the page itself.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API